# Is there any way to record internal sound of the mobile

Tags: android

I am making a drum app in which the user tap and the sound plays, but the problem is using media recorder the output source is set to mic and the outer sounds are recorded to i want to only record the sound of the drum

Looking forward for your helps

Comment: i want to record the internal sound of an application.

Comment: What do you mean by internal sound? You are using `MediaRecorder` to record sound but you want to record the sound of the drum only? If I understood correctly, you want to record the user's drum playing session?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad yes